# Symbian: sign sis file

Tags: mobile, symbian

I'm developing an application for S60 3rd Edition FP1 mobile phones.

The application uses Location capability, which means that we need more than just a self-signed sis file to deploy it. To use Location capability in FP1 mobile devices, we need to sign the application using the Open Online Signed option. However, this process is not automatic. It requires access to the symbiansigned.com website.

Does anyone knows a way to sign the sis file using Open Online Signed option just after building the project in Carbide c++, similar to the self-signed way?

Thanks, 
Fernando

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mean automated and integrated into the build and test cycle?  Unfortunately no, I don't think it's possible at the moment.

The Symbian Foundation are currently working on a way to get developer certificates back to developers so you don't have to use open signed online.  The other alternative would be to write your own plugin for Carbide.c++.

EDIT: In your particular case, a good option may be to do most of your development on the FP1 SDK but deploy to an FP2 phone (where you can self-sign for Location) and just test occasionally on an FP1 phone (and more extensively at the end of course).

Comment: Does every feature supported in FP1 also work for FP2? Or is there some known incompatibilities?

Thanks again.

Comment: In general, yes there is backwards compatibility.  There are some minor incompatibilities.  Anything major will be in the FP2 SDK release notes but the minor things tend to be discovered after the release of the SDK and get documented on the Forum Nokia wiki.